# What exactly is the Concerns folder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

I recently saw a folder called `Concerns` in Laravel, and did not understand what exactly it is? The only thing I understood about this was that it is just traits!

- Can anyone give me information about this folder?
- What kind of `traits` are `concerns`?
- What is the difference between normal `traits` and `concerns`?

Some references:

- [Database Concerns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns)
- [Console Concerns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns)
- [Http Concerns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns)
- [View Concerncs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns)
- [Laravel Dusk Concerncs](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/tree/6.x/src/Concerns)

Comment: The naming comes from the design pattern: Seperation of Concerns

Comment: Laravel writes concerns as traits. Concerns are an OOP programming paradigm while traits are a PHP language feature that can allow the implementation of this paradigm they are not the only one and traits are not the only way to separate concerns, Laravel just chooses this way in certain parts.